# SocketException: The requested address is not valid in the context

Tags: c#, sockets, unity-game-engine, socketexception

I am able to communicate with socketTest with the same ip address, but within UNITY I get an error message

> SocketException: The requested address is not valid in the context.

I tried

```
socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(sHostIpAddress), nPort));
```

`sHostIpAddress` is **not** `127.0.0.1`

How to can i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really specific to `Unity` but rather `c#` in general.

[`Socket.Bind`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.bind) is for binding the socket to a specific **local** endpoint! Such as for example you want to limit the socket to a specific local network adapter / address (by default it will use any/all) or a specific local port (by default it will pick any free local port)

> Use the `Bind` method if you **need to** use a specific **local** endpoint. You must call `Bind` before you can call the `Listen` method. **You do not need to call `Bind` before using the `Connect` method unless you need to use a specific local endpoint**.

Usually you use `Bind` mostly for the server side for listening and waiting for incoming connections or for connectionless protocols like `UDP`.

You most probably simply want to rather use [`Socket.Connect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.connect) for establishing a connection to a **remote** server.

When using `Connect` without `Bind` then it will simply pick the network adapter / address it finds to be the best fit for reaching the given host address and picks the next free local port.

---

However, in general I would recommend to rather use [`TcpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient) instead of composing and configuring the `Socket` "manually" (except the use case requires it).

```
var tcpClient = new TcpClient(sHostIpAddress, nPort);
```

This constructor will automatically start a connection attempt. `TcpClient` is an `IDisposable` and cleans up the underlying socket, stream etc when it is disposed. It also is (in my eyes) way easier to configure and to sent and receive data with it.

Comment: Thanks for reply, thanks to your help i solved it. : )